# Rails update a field with another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, a table `_tbl` with `field_1`, `field_2`.

In Rails, using `update_all` or other methods in `activerecord`, is it possible to create sql like `UPDATE _tbl SET field_1 = field_2` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ModelName.update_all("field_1 = field_2")
```